# Laravel 419 page expired при оплате через free kassa

Tags: laravel, csrf, платежи, free-kassa

Я встроил виджет free kassa на сайт. Когда происходит оплата, их сервер отправляет `POST` запрос на `/payment/result`.
В логах free kassa написано, что была ошибка 419 page expired. Это из-за того ,что не передается csrf токен. Значит нужно добавить этот url в исключение.

web.php

```js
// web.php

// Роут, на который free kassa шлёт запрос
Route::post('/payment/result', function (Request $request){
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($request->all());
    return 123;
})->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\FreeKassaVerifyCsrfToken::class);


Route::any('/{any}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

VerifyCsrfToken.php

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
   protected $except = [
        '/payment/result',
    ];
}
```

Я создал middleware `FreeKassaVerifyCsrfToken` для обработки роутов free kassa, но при оплате по запросу `/payment/result` ошибка `419 page expired`.

```js
use Illuminate\ Foundation\ Http\ Middleware\ VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class FreeKassaVerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware {

  private $whiteList = [
    '136.243.38.147',
    '136.243.38.149',
    '136.243.38.150',
    '136.243.38.151',
    '136.243.38.189',
    '136.243.38.108',
    '136.243.38.*',
  ];

  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
   * @param \Closure $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public
  function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    Log::info('123');
    if (!in_array($request - > ip(), $this - > whiteList)) {
      abort(403);
    }
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

В лог файл тоже ничего не выводится, то есть `handler` даже не срабатывает.
Но, если в web.php прицепить middleware `FreeKassaVerifyCsrfToken` к роуту `/{any}`, то при любых запросах - 403 ошибка, и в лог выводится `123`
В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: А зачем Вы вообще проверяете токен для этого роута? Просто блокируйте любой реквест, который пришёл не со списка разрешенных IP кассы.

Comment: Так вот же. я скинул VerifyCsrfToken.php, в котором я исключаю ip free kassa из csrf проверки. Но это не работает

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Но при этом в web.php Вы его навешиваете, а затем исключаете. Зачем?

Comment: Не надо `VerifyCsrfToken` навешивать в вебе, а экспект работает по другому, он исключает те маршруты которые есть в вашем приложении, в експект отключаете проверку csrf токена своего маршрута, а в роутинге добавляете проверку на ip. Ну или как лучше так это сделать мидлварь которая проверяет апишки фрикассы

Comment: Ну и как дополнение добавлю: `VerifyCsrfToken` эта мидлварь вешается через кернел http на все веб запросы

Comment: Я что-то не понимаю. `VerifyCsrfToken->except` добавляет в исключение csrf проверки или что он делает? По документации я понял, что, в `$except` пишется массив разрешенных url. Там даже есть пример с платёжкой `ripple` вроде. И вы говорите, в `web.php` вешать и исключать не надо. Тогда как это сделать?

Comment: Исключение на маршрут который есть в вашем приложении

Comment: @Walfter я обновил код в вопросе

Comment: Зачем вы наследуетесь от VerifyCsrf??? Надо от обычной мидлвари. Создайте мидлварь через `php artisan make:middleware` и её уже опишите

Comment: Я так и так пробовал) Но ваш ответ оказался правильным, это я немного затупил. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мидлварь `VerifyCsrfToken` исключает маршруты которые есть в внутри вашего приложения, метод except принимает значения урлов из роутинга с мидлварной группой web

Теперь о ваших черепахах. У вас есть пост запрос такого типа

```
// web.php
Route::post('/payment/result', function(Request $request) {\
    Illuminate\ Support\ Facades\ Log::info($request - > all());
  });
});
```

Вешаем его в исключения CSRF защиты

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/payment/result',
    ];
}
```

Делаем свою мидлварь для обработки уролов фри кассы с хандлером типа

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!in_array($request->ip(), $this->whiteList)) {
        abort(403);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

P.S.: Пропа `whiteList` содержит массив разрешённых апишников для доступа к этому маршруту

Теперь далее: регистрируем созданную мидлварь для роута

```
// web.php
Route::post('/payment/result', function(Request $request) {
    Illuminate\ Support\ Facades\ Log::info($request - > all());
  });
})->middleware(YourMiddleware::class);
```

Если вкратце то как то так.

**UPDATE:**

Мидлварь VerifyCsrfToken цепляется через kernel который лежит в папке http на группу web по этому его не надо вручную добавлять к роутам, все роутый из файла web.php уже имеют эту группу на уровне роут провайдера

Comment: У меня всё равно почему-то не работает, ошибок никаких нет

Comment: В `handler` я написал `Log:info(123);`. Но при оплате он не срабатывает. Если нацепить на другой роут и открыть его, то ошибка 403, как и должно быть

Comment: @Colorkat В хандлер чего?

Comment: В handler'е своего middleware для обработки url free kass'ы

Comment: Мидлварь в роуте прикреплена?

Comment: Да, точно так же, как и у вас в примере

Comment: я попробовал через postman отправить POST запрос на эту страницу - ошибка 403. Тогда я добавил в `$whiteList` `127.0.0.1` - роут сработал, как надо. Может мне `ip` кассы дали неправильные?

Comment: @Colorkat не уверен что вам дали не верные айпишки, вы уверены что у вас хук на этот маршрут шлёт? Если он вообще в хандлер не заходит у мидлвари стоит подумать что у вас какие то другие настройки